# Changing height of container with TextField

Tags: flutter

How can I change the height of a container and automatically bring the cursor to the next line a line gets filled ( similar to WhatsApp where we type the message ) in flutter?
Here is my code: 
Positioned(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.03 ,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

```
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){

                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ),
                EditableText(
                  expands: true,
                  maxLines: null,
                  minLines: null,
                  style: kTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0),
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  scrollPhysics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  enableSuggestions: true,
                  controller: _chattextcontroller,
                  backgroundCursorColor: Colors.grey,
                  focusNode: FocusNode(),

                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: (){

                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.send,
                 ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `EditableText` widget:

```
EditableText(
    expands: true,
    maxLines: null,
    minLines: null,
    //other required params
),
```

Comment: Please check my edited code in the question. I don't know why but blank screen is being displayed. I have put the whole code inside a Positioned widget.

Comment: I think that it works but you can't see the editable text bcz has no background color
try wrapping it inside a Container and give the container a color and you will see where it is

Answer (score 0):

**The following code might help you and set no. of max lines you needed.**

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(),
            ),
            child: const TextField(
              maxLines: 5,
              minLines: 1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Hint",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```